# Incorrect Responsiveness of \overleftrightarrow using STIX 2.0 Fonts

Tags: luatex, stix

I'm trying to use STIX 2.0 fonts and typeset a file using lualatex. I faced an issue on the `\overleftrightarrow` as it is not responsive correctly.

This is the code I use:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmainfont{STIX2Text-Regular.otf}
\setmathfont[StylisticSet=8]{STIX2Math.otf}

\begin{document}
$\overleftrightarrow{ABC}$
\end{document}
```

And here is the output:

[image]

I expected the output to be like this:

[image]

Are there any solution for this issue?

Comment: See https://sourceforge.net/p/stixfonts/tracking/97/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently, U+020E1 is not extensible in STIX2, whereas it is in STIX (v. 1) and in XITS Math.

Workaround:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmainfont{STIX Two Text}
\setmathfont[StylisticSet=8]{STIX Two Math}
\setmathfont[range=\overleftrightarrow]{XITS Math}

\begin{document}

$\overleftrightarrow{ABC}+\overleftarrow{ABC}+\overrightarrow{ABC}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: i assume that you were the one who reportrd the problem on github.  thanks.

Comment: @barbarabeeton No, I found a bug report about the issue and added some information.